# CXF Bundles: Whats the difference?

Tags: apache, web-services, maven, cxf, ivy

I'm using maven, but I dont understand the difference between following dependencies:

1.)
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.cxf/cxf-bundle/3.0.0-milestone2

2.)
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.cxf/cxf-bundle-compatible/3.0.3

Option 2 seems newer, but can I use it?

At the moment I use "http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.cxf/cxf-bundle/2.7.14", but I want to upgrade to V. 3.x.x

I haven't found any informations about the cxf-bundle/3.0.0-milestone2 yet, but perhaps someone knows, whre to find more informations about this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The big monolithic bundle was removed in 3.0.   Use the individual bundles that you need for your application.

Comment: Where can I find a list of available bundles? Thx!